# AWS Amplify Custom Domain Connection to Google Domains Stuck on SSL Config

Tags: dns, ssl, amazon-web-services, domain

I am working on setting up a custom domain for a GitHub repo that I am hosting on Amplify and I have configured to the best of my ability the connection between AWS and Google Domains. As of right now AWS is stuck at SSL Configuration.[image: ssl config]

I have copied over the CNAME information to Google Domains:

- `*  CNAME  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amplifyapp.com.`
- `www  CNAME  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.acm.validations.aws`

[image]

I have checked my DNS and it seems to be working on whatsmydns.net and that seems to be good. I did all of this last night and let it sit overnight to see if it would sync, but nothing seems to be happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer at this blog: https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-deploy-a-custom-domain-with-the-amplify-console-a884b6a3c0fc

1. Go to AWS dashboard > Route53 > Hosted Zones > Create Hosted Zone
2. Enter your custom domain without www & hit create
3. Copy all generated NS values, set them as custom nameservers at Google Domains
4. Wait DNS to propagate